# Styles not working in new theme Drupal 8

Tags: drupal, drupal-theming, drupal-8

I´m trying to create my theme (Drupal 8.0.2)
So, in my drupal folder, **drupal->themes->custom**

I have my theme folder: **themex**

There I have my **themex.info.yml**

```
name: themex
type: theme
base theme: classy
description: themex description
core: 8.x
screenshot: screenshot.png
libraries:
  - themex/global-styling
stylesheets-remove:
  - '@classy/css/components/tabs.css'
  - core/assets/vendor/normalize-css/normalize.css
regions:
  header: Header
  content: Content
  sidebar_first: 'Sidebar first'
  footer: Footer
```

My **themex.libraries.yml**

```
global-styling:
  version: 1.x
  css:
    theme:
      css/styles.css: {}
  js:
    js/myjavascript.js: {}
  dependencies:
    - core/jquery

font-awesome:
  remote: https://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/
  version: 4.5.0
  license:
    name: MIT
    url: https://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/license/
    gpl-compatible: true
  css:
    theme:
      https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css: { type: external, minified: true }
```

Inside the folder **css** I have my **styles.css**

```
body { 
    background-color: #000000; 
    font-family: 'Open Sans', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 50px; 
    }
```

I installed and set themex as default.

Also I unchecked

Aggregate CSS files

Aggregate JavaScript files

Then Clear all caches

But... **My style is not being implemented. Anyone knows WHY...?**
Thanks a lot!

Comment: if you inspect the page, do you see a file not found error ? is the head of the html looking for the css ? are you creating a theme from scratch or subtheming another theme (such as bootstrap) ?

Comment: After running `drush cache-rebuild` can you inspect the html source? Can you now find the string "/themes/themex/css/style.css" somewhere?